# Trouble creating a range with a Celsius to Fahrenheit converter in Python3

Tags: python-3.x

I've got a homework question today. My instructions are to

> Modify the convert.py program so that it prints a table of Celsius
>   temperatures and Fahrenheit equivalents from 0-100 degrees in steps of
>   10. Format results in nice columns to two decimal places.

So I've got a working Celsius to Fahrenheit converter, but I have no idea how to make the table in steps of 10.

```
def c2f():

   celsius = float(input("What is the Celsius temperature? "))

   fahrenheit = 9/5 * celsius + 32

   print("The temperature {1} is {0:,.2f} degrees Fahrenheit.".format(fahrenheit, celsius))

c2f()
```

Once the code is working it should show two columns, one with Celsius, and the other with Fahrenheit increasing by 10 degrees Celsius with every row in the column, ranging from 0 to 100 degrees Celsius, for a total of 10 rows.

Answer (score 1):

**I have produced some annotated code below.**

Start off by initializing the list of Celsius values.
Then, Create a DataFrame to hold the data.  Finally, convert the list of Celsius values and append the values to the DataFrame under a new column.

*Note: there are multiple ways of completing this assignment.*

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def c2f(celsius):
    print(celsius)
    fahrenheit = (9 * celsius / 5) + 32
    print("The temperature {1} is {0:,.2f} degrees Fahrenheit.".format(fahrenheit, 
celsius))
    return fahrenheit

#initialize list of values ranging from 0 through 100 counting by 10s
list_celcius = np.arange(11)*10

#Create DataFrame with column "Celcius"    
df = pd.DataFrame({'Celcius': list_celcius})

#Append calculated values into Fahrenheit column in DataFrame
df['Fahrenheit'] = [c2f(list_celcius[i]) for i in range(len(list_celcius))]

print(df)
```

Comment: What does {0:,.2f} change in the code? The converter still works if I change it to just {0}

Comment: cupcake, .2f designates the amount of decimals places that will be printed.  The Dataframe will be printed with print(df)

Comment: A solution that requires Numpy and Panda DataFrames is more than a little overkill for such a simple assignment, especially for an obvious beginner.  Given that this is a homework assignment, perhaps that was the intent?

Answer (score 0):

A few suggestions:

- Read the assignment a few more times.
- Remove the not required `input` line from the `c2f()` definition.
- Remove the not required `print` line from the `c2f()` definition.
- Read the assignment a few more times.
- Learn how to define functions with parameters and return values.
- Add a `celsius` parameter to the `c2f()` definition.
- Add a `return` line to the `c2f()` definition.
- Read the assignment a few more times.

You now have a `f = c2f(celsius)` function to work with.

And continue:

- Read the assignment a few more times.
- Learn how to write iterative loops.
- Write a loop that iterates on `celsius` with values from 0 to 100 by 10.
- Call `c2f()` on each iteration.
- Display the current `celsius` value and the corresponding `c2f()` value on each iteration.

Comment: I think that i just need to modify this part of the code:{0:,.2f}. I'm very new to this, and the code that I have provided is meant to be modified to show the two columns.